# how to view log output in Azure function app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-monitoring

in the azure function app code below, I am calling _logger.LogInformation.

```
namespace streaminfo
{
    public class someTrigger
    {
        private readonly ILogger<someTrigger> _logger;
        public someTrigger(ILogger<someTrigger> log)
        {                _logger = log;
        }

        [FunctionName("someTrigger")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mytopic", "my-sub", Connection = "endpoint")]string mySbMsg)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");

        }
    }
}
```

The above code is generated by microsoft when you create a new function app in latest visual studio.

If I use the "stream logs" tab in the azure page for the function app resource, I see a log entry each time the function is triggered, but I dont see my log output.

```
2022-06-07T11:29:43.447 [Information] Executing 'someTrigger' (Reason='(null)', Id=c0cb129f-e005-4d4c-98c5-b15c8d1e534c)
2022-06-07T11:29:43.447 [Information] Trigger Details: MessageId: 5920aa34-da72-404b-a0b2-766a73e1f9ba, SequenceNumber: 51791395714760792, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2022-06-07T11:29:43.3910000Z, LockedUntilUtc: 2022-06-07T11:30:43.4060000Z, SessionId: (null)
2022-06-07T11:29:43.447 [Information] Executed 'someTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=c0cb129f-e005-4d4c-98c5-b15c8d1e534c, Duration=0ms)
```

How do I view log output?  Maybe its log level?

Answer (score 2):

As you're using `ILogger<T>`, by default, those logs will not appear. This documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#iloggert-and-iloggerfactory

> The host injects ILogger and ILoggerFactory services into constructors. However, by default these new logging filters are filtered out of the function logs. You need to modify the host.json file to opt-in to additional filters and categories.

This tripped me up a few times in the past. Changing it to ILogger (not the generic) should work out of the box, but otherwise you just need to update the log filters in host.json.

Example is in the above MS link, but:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        },
        "logLevel": {
            "MyNamespace.HttpTrigger": "Information" // THIS BIT
        }
    }
}
```

The first thing I tend to do when setting up a new functions app now, is to add a filter for my root namespace (e.g. `{"MyRootNamespace.": "Information"}`), to include everything from my root down.

While you *could* switch to ILogger, I don't generally believe that's practical or a good idea - e.g. if you have existing class libraries that use `ILogger<T>` or another dev comes along and uses the generic - you're better off just ensuring you're not filtering them out by tweaking host.json.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it with the built-in Function App *Logger*:

```cs
namespace streaminfo
{
    public class someTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("someTrigger")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mytopic", "my-sub", Connection = "endpoint")] string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
        }
    }
}
```

I guess, you have to do additional configuration (Startup / Settings) for your implementation.

Default Azure Function [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example):

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyFunctions
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the usings:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
...

Please have a look at the MS Docs example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example

Comment: I tried your code thanks. same result unfortunately.

Comment: How did you create the Function? VS Code? Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The code for ServiceBus trigger looks like this:

```
[FunctionName("Test")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mytopic", "mysubscription", Connection = "")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)

        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
        }
```

where the ILogger is passed to the function, have you tried it? in the sample provided the ILogger is a member of the class.

also how did you generate this code, using cli or via vscode?

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace streaminfo
{
    public class someTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("someTrigger")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mytopic", "my-sub", Connection = "endpoint")] string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
        }
    }
}
```