# Where does ILogger<TCategoryName> write to?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm writing a Function App which trimmed down comes to this

```
namespace myNamespace {
    public class Test {
        private readonly ILogger _Constructorlog;
         public Test(ILogger<TestProcessor> logger) {
            _Constructorlog = logger;
        }

        [FunctionName("TestLog")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RunWeb([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger methodLog) {
            methodLog.LogInformation("method log");
            _Constructorlog.LogInformation("Constructor log");
        }
    }
}
```

This code writes this to the Console window as expected

`[2022-07-06T10:07:35.302Z] method log`

Where should "Constructor log" be written?

`_Constructorlog` is of type `ILogger<TestProcessor>` when `LogInformation` is called.

This is the `hosts.json' file

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried using the various JSON from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Depends on how logging is configured in appSettings.json file

Comment: I've added the hosts.json file to the question

Comment: So to be clear, you do see "method log" in the console AND application insights but you don't see "Constructor log" anywhere?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct

Comment: By default, Logger<T> logs are filtered out - looks like that's the issue. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72530701/how-to-view-log-output-in-azure-function-app/72532323 - it's the logLevel section under logging in host.json that you need to add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace needs adding into `host.json` for the class.

```
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        },
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "None",
            "myNamespace": "Information"
        }
    }
}
```

`None` here stops Dependency Injected `ILogger` `.LogInformation` being shown in the Console window, so `method log` isn't written.

Adding `Information` to the namespace here means `ILogger<TCategoryName>` `.LogInformation` for that namespace are written in the Console window.

Removing `"default": "None",` writes both to the Console window.

I need to test how these settings apply when it's uploaded to Azure, but this works locally.